# How to convert *.cur (Windows cursor) stream to bitmap?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, cursor, delphi-2010

It's easy to convert from cur-file to bitmap, using the LoadCursorFromFile API call and calling DrawIcon(..., hCursor) on that bitmap.

But how can I load it from stream without too much handcoding and convert into TBitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Kicon](http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kicon.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is an [MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) that describes the .cur and .ico file formats in great detail.  It's pretty easy – I wrote some Delphi code to read .ico files not so long ago using this article as my reference.

Comment: It's not really in a form to share because it only does a very limited task which is not what you need.  I'm sure there are libraries out there.  Do you know about the Windows API GetIconInfo?  You can pass that an HICON and get back an HBITMAP.  You can then take bmp: TBitmap and write bmp.Handle := hBmp.  Would that do the trick for you?

Comment: Also, do you need to know about the mask image?  And I guess that modern cursors are alpha blended so they'll probably come out of GetIconInfo with the mask bitmap handle NULL and a 32bpp bitmap with alpha channel in the main bitmap handle.